# Set expiration date for file sharing permission using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I want to use the google script to share a file as view only (and download, print and sharing disabled) with a group of users and also set the an expiration date for this, so that after the set time the file is automatically un-shared with this group of users.

I am able to do the some of the above, but I have not been able to set expiration date through script.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you want you need to use [Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) and Apps Script.

For a single file, you can create a script on it that has the following function:

```
function RemoveAllAccess() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("file ID here");
  var viewers = file.getViewers();
  for (var i=0; i<viewers.length; i++) {
    file.removeViewer(viewers[i]);
  }
}
```

Then create a trigger for the date you want to revoke reading permissions like this:
[image: Trigger UI]

Alternatively, you could create a single sheet, where you input the `sheet ID` (or URL) and the `date` that you want to revoke the access at.

To simplify this, you can create a script that runs daily (via trigger).
This script will reads all lines and checks if the date on that line is `<= today - 1 day`. If that's the case, then trigger the script provided above with the correct file ID to remove all permissions.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I need to customize the time for each file. e.g.  5 days after a file is shared, it should be un-shared. Also, the file will be shared with a "user group",

Comment: You can do this with another script (maybe an auxiliary sheet where you place the sheet URL and the date you want to stop the sharing) and have that replicated. I will update the answer to have that possibility tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you! I tried using the update permissions code from https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/update#examples   But I am getting referenceError: "gapi" is not defined.

Comment: You are looking at the wrong part of the documentation. What you are running is Google Apps Script, not Java. Here is the link to the correct documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file

Comment: I did try the link you shared and found a way to implement what I was trying to achieve using that. But I am still wondering  if I was able to use the Drive.Permissions.insert then why am I not able to use Drive.Permissions.update.